# Labels not appearing over selected features

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, labeling

I have turned on the labels over a map of the United States, and I have to select several spatial features (ten U.S. states). When I select the states, the labels disappear under the fill color (which I cannot change). I know this is simple, but I am very new to this and cannot think of  a solution. I have already tried several things.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: ArcMap 10.1. I thought that the site was specific to that; my mistake. I found this in a hurry and must not have read carefully enough.

Comment: I'm not sure why the selection is disabling the labeling, but you try changing the selection symbol: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/29435

Comment: Would you be able to list your precise steps because I have not been able to reproduce what you describe?

Answer (score 1):

I believe a work around is to export the 10 states, add them to the top of table of contents, and set up the desired symbology and label.